# can i replace a illuminated dimmer switch with a wyze smart switch if i can't identify a neutral wire

Tags: electrical

Older 50s built home can't tell if I have a neutral wire looking to replace ceiling fan illuminated dimmer switch with a wyze smart switch

Comment: electricity does not works without neutral

Comment: Please show photos of existing wiring and proposed wiring

Comment: @Ruskes Electricity does not work without a return path. But that path is not always neutral. If it was, no: large water heater (tanked or tankless), EVSE (a.k.a., car charger), large resistance electric heater or similar device would work in US residential applications.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box in question please?

Answer (score 1):

No.

A Wyze switch can't control a dual function device like a fan with light unless the fan and light are also smart.  The switch can't provide dimming unless you use smart bulbs. It is not illuminated.  (It has a light, but that does the opposite of what your old one does.)

If you don't have a neutral wire you can't install it.  It won't work at all.

If you truly *cannot tell* if you have a neutral wire you should not be working on it.  If you know enough to turn off the breaker and take pictures of the open switch box you can ask a new question seeking help with that.  Don't disconnect anything.  Just unravel the wires as best you can and take a well lit well focused picture.

But again, this switch can't replace an illuminated fan-light controller, with or without a neutral.

Comment: Wyze does make dimmers too. But yes, separate control requires separate switches/controllers, and Wyde doesn't (afaik) make that variant.

Comment: I think the OP is looking to replace an _illuminated dimmer switch_ that controls a ceiling fan, not necessarily a ceiling fan with illumination. Unless I'm totally misreading that...

Comment: @FreeMan the question says nothing specific about a ceiling light but I'm assuming "dimmer" is somehow relevant.

Comment: Could be a 3-speed fan controller or a dimmer improperly used as a fan controller. Yet another in a series of not particularly specific questions. Good communications is difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Wyze, in particular, does not seem to currently offer a combined smart switch device to control a ceiling fan with a light fixture.

Such devices do exists and can be found with a bit of searching. I've ordered two different units -- different brands -- from the same online bookstore. One has a dimmer for the light and only switches the fan; the other has a speed controller for the fan but only a switch for the light. Both connected successfully to my home automation (both Smart things and Alexa), one via Zigby (which I prefer since it keeps control local) and one via WiFi.

HOWEVER, almost every smart switch requires neutral at the switch box. This makes them unusable if your place was wired with "switch loops" that don't include neutral. I have that problem in several other rooms. The best solution I've found is to get a "smart" controller that installs at the fan rather than at the switch; by definition neutral *will* be available there. Again, there are multiple manufacturers; the folks who made the fan may offer one, and there are the same scattering of second sources.

CAVEAT: Some of these products may not have passed US safety codes. You should probably be careful when purchasing. Malfunctioning switches *can* start house fires. I have to admit I've been less cautious about that than I probably should be.